How do I deal with plagues?
I have started several new games starting in the earldom of Desmond, and within the first month or so in-game, I have had my earldom infected by a plague. I have employed a personal physician and had them Control Plagues, however, even with a physician with a good aptitude, I have had my entire court and house wiped out by the plague.
What other options do I have for combating the plague in the early game?

TBH the game mechanics are so unbalanced by strange updates that the game is pretty much unplayable at this point. Plagues are just lottery. The options you have is to move your family into hiding as well as to close down the capital. Neither seems to have much of an impact.

Plagues are a bit of a lottery, where you can only influence your odds.
Apart from what you already did (the physician and isolating the capital), there is also a chance to have an Isolate Court option (if your Chancellor has a high enough skill).
Personally, I think health boosts help the most. So, creating a character with health boost traits and the Whole of Body branch of the Learning Lifestyle would be especially beneficial.
